MS Graph Api Colorize Line in Excel
I want to color a row in an Excel spreadsheet using C# code and the Graph API.
It works in the Graph Explorer:
patch https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveid}/items/{itemid}/workbook/worksheets/Tabelle1/range(address='A5:H5')/format/fill

In C# there is an error with the following code:
var formatRequestBody = new WorkbookRangeFormat
{
    Fill = new WorkbookRangeFill
    {
        Color = "#FFF00" // Gelbe Farbe
    }
};
await graphClient.Drives[driveId]
    .Items[FileId]
    .Workbook
    .Worksheets["Tabelle1"]
    .RangeWithAddress($"A{row.Index + 1}:H{row.Index + 1}")
    .Format
    .PatchAsync(formatRequestBody);

The Error is:
{"The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format."}

Based on the endpoint, the code should be like ...Format.Fill.PatchAsync(body)
var fillRequestBody = new WorkbookRangeFill
{
    Color = "#FFF00" // Gelbe Farbe
};
await graphClient.Drives[driveId]
    .Items[FileId]
    .Workbook
    .Worksheets["Tabelle1"]
    .RangeWithAddress($"A{row.Index + 1}:H{row.Index + 1}")
    .Format
    .Fill
    .PatchAsync(fillRequestBody);

But the Fill request builder is missing in the SDK, so it would better to report an issue in the SDK repository.
